# Confusion regarding the setting the property of a parent object from child object in javascript

Tags: javascript

Say we have a code example like this :

```
var obj1={ prop:1 };
var obj2=Object.create(obj1);
obj2.prop=2;
console.log(obj1.prop);
```

Here we will have output as `1` because in the child object `obj2` the property `prop` will be shadowed. However when I do this :

```
var obj1={ prop:{subProp:1} };
var obj2=Object.create(obj1);
obj2.prop.subProp=2;
console.log(obj1.prop.subProp);
```

Here surprisingly I find that the output is `2` despite the fact that the value is being changed on the child object. Why isn't variable shadowing taking place here. In other words why isin't a new property called `prop` being created on `obj2` and why is the `prop` of the parent object ( `obj1` ) being manipulated here ?

EDIT : If I do the following

```
var obj1={ prop:1 };
var obj2=Object.create(obj1);
var isPresent=obj2.hasOwnProperty('prop');
console.log(isPresent);
```

here output will be false. However :

```
var obj1={ prop:1 };
var obj2=Object.create(obj1);
var isPresent=obj2.hasOwnProperty('prop');
console.log(isPresent);
obj2.prop=2;
isPresent=obj2.hasOwnProperty('prop');
console.log(isPresent);
```

Here as you can see after the line `obj2.prop=2` the output is true. That is also confusing me.

Comment: You might find [*The Resolution of Property Names on Objects*](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/#clResO) useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because when you create `obj2`, none of the properties gets copied but `obj2`'s prototype become `obj1`. This means that on read, the engine look for properties in the whole prototype chain and on write, you just write to the object.

What happen when you do `obj2.prop = 2` is that you write to `obj2` directly but when you do `obj2.prop.subProp = 2` you are first asking the engine to read `obj2.prop` and then write to that object some value.

In the second example, you never write directly to `obj2` so `obj2` is still "empty" (you could check that by using `obj2.hasOwnProperty('prop')` after each example as you suggested in a comment)

Comment: However when add this line obj2.hasOwnProperty('prop') before I set obj2.prop=2; in the first case, I get false as answer . But woudnt that imply prop does not exist in the obj2 at that point ??

Comment: Oups, I misunderstood the problem. You are totally right, I edited the answer completely to correct this mistake.

Comment: @KiranYallabandi You may find [this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes#javascript-prototypal-inheritance) quick intro to JavaScript Prototypal Inheritance useful.

Comment: @Clement Prevost Thanks for the clarification. Currently I'm referring "you dont know JS" series of books there it is mentioned  that whenever object lookup happens [[get]] is used and for object assignment [[put]] is used. Would it be possible for you to give me a link to a site where the solution to my problem is explained in those terms ??

Comment: Well, that's a very specific request, but I'm not aware of a normalised way to name those operations so unfortunately you'll have to adapt to the writer preference.

Comment: @Clement Prevost Alright but thanks anyway